# Text alignment differs between canvas and HTML

Tags: html, css, canvas, text, alignment

I want to be able to switch between canvas and HTML view with the same result but It already fails when I'm trying to center text inside an area. How can I fix the example below so that the both labels overlap exactly indepentent from the font family and size.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
ctx.font = '64px Tahoma';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.fillStyle = 'BlueViolet';
ctx.fillText('Hello World!', 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas
  height="160"
  id="canvas"
  style="
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  "
  width="480"
></canvas>
<div
  style="
    align-items: center;
    color: FireBrick;
    display: flex;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 64px;
    height: 160px;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 480px;
  "
>Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you adjust the **ctx.translate** to make it work? If yes, change to the following: `canvas.height/2+6`

```
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2+6);
```

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2+6);
ctx.font = '64px Tahoma';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.fillStyle = 'BlueViolet';
ctx.fillText('Hello World!', 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas
  height="160"
  id="canvas"
  style="
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  "
  width="480"
></canvas>
<div
  style="
    align-items: center;
    color: FireBrick;
    display: flex;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 64px;
    height: 160px;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 480px;
  "
>Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But it should be independent from the font settings.